# GroupBy with shared index or Play 2 repeated forms

Tags: scala, functional-programming, playframework-2.0

Im trying to make an order form with Play 2 and Scala.

Here is what it was before grouping:

```
<table>
  @items.zipWithIndex.map {
    case (item, index) =>
      @itemRow(item, index)
  }
</table>
```

itemRow definition

```
@itemRow(index: Int, item: Item) = {
    <tr>
        <td>
        @(index+1)
        </td>
        <td>
        @item.name
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="hidden" name="@requestForm("items")("[" + index + "]")("itemId").name" value="@item.id">
            <input type="text" name="items[@index].count" value="@requestForm("items")("[" + index + "]")("count").value">

        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

At first I tried naive implementation

```
@items.groupBy(item => item.category).map {
  case (categoryId, itemsInCategory) =>
    <table>
      @itemsInCategory.zipWithIndex.map {
        case (item, index) =>
          @itemRow(item, index)
      }
    </table>
}
```

But there is a problem, indexes in each category starts with 0.

So, http request is something like that:

```
# category 1
items[0].id = 1
items[0].count = 1
items[1].id = 2
items[1].count = 2

# category 2
items[0].id = 3
items[0].count = 1
items[1].id = 4
items[1].count = 5
```

And it is causes to values being overriden.
I need my indexes for be consecutive within the form, like this:

```
# category 1
items[0].id = 1
items[0].count = 1
items[1].id = 2
items[1].count = 2

# category 2
items[2].id = 3
items[2].count = 1
items[3].id = 4
items[3].count = 5
```

## So there is questions

For functional programmers:

- Can I make index variable shared for all groups?

For Play 2.0 or web programmers:

- Is there another way to make form with variable count of repeated values?
- How to avoid sending this bunch of items with 0 count?

Comment: Do you need the indexes in each group to be consecutive or not?

Comment: How about actually using the power of Play? "@repeat( (_form("foo")), min=numFoo) {x=> @inputText(x("someField"), ...) }" and have the framework do all of the work for you

Comment: @virtualeyes as i get it, `@repeat` is working with form with already  filled data. Also, can't imagine how fit repeated in table. Can u write answer in detail?

Comment: @repeat will fill or produce an empty form. Have you looked at the Play 2 docs??? "http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0.4/ScalaFormHelpers" When possible avoid manually constructing forms, Play can do a ton of work for you if you let it.

Comment: @virtualeyes yep, i've looked it. But I don't know how to make with it what I want. Docs are superficial and I can't find anything on this topic in internet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no experience with Play so I can't comment on the Play specific questions (maybe it already provides helpers for what you want), but on the scala librayr alone you can do something like this:

```
@items.sortBy(item => item.category).zipWithIndex.groupBy{ case (item, _) => item.category}.map {
  case (categoryId, indexedItemsInCategory) =>
    <table>
      @indexedItemsInCategory.map {
        case (item, index) =>
          @itemRow(item, index)
      }
    </table>
}
```

The idea is to first sort the items by category and then zip them with the corresponding indexes. Then only you group them by category (which should be fast as the list is already sorted).